# The time of each step of the loop problem in C

Tags: c, time, clock

As the name suggests, I have a problem with the clock() function.

I want the time of each step in the loop to be printed.

For example, I have code:

```
#include<time.h>
int main()
{
    clock_t start,end;
    for(int i=0;i<number_of_elements;i++)
    {
        start=clock();
        for(int z=/*something*/;z>=0;z--)
        {
            //Some desired processing
        }
        for(int g=0;g</*something*/;g++)
        {
            //Some desired processing
        }
    
       end=clock();
       double duration=(double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
       printf("%d.step %f\n",i+1,duration);
    }

}
```

And now I want to print the time of each step from 'i' in this loop.
But what I get are only zeros.

Example:

```
1.step 0.000000
2.step 0.000000
3.step 0.000000
4.step 0.000000
etc.
```

Can anyone help me about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I still have the same problem.

Comment: Maybe your times are too small. Look at it in the debugger and/or insert some delay with `sleep`

Comment: Maye print `start` and `end` directly fist. Also print `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. How long does your code take between the two calls of `clock`? If it is less than `1s/CLOCKS_PER_SEC` you will barely see any difference in both values.

Comment: Your code seems correct.  No need to force the cast to double.

Comment: Yes, the interval between the beginning and the end seems to be very small. Is there a way to display that interval somehow in smaller units than a second?

Comment: Using big numbers where `/*something*/` in the `for` loops will produce bigger times

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your code template with this

```
#include<time.h>
int main()
{
    clock_t start,end;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        start=clock();
        for(int z=3;z>=0;z--)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        for(int g=0;g<3;g++)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    
       end=clock();
       double duration=(double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
       printf("%d.step %f\n",i+1,duration);
    }

}
```

And the output was this:

```
1.step 0.000077







2.step 0.000005







3.step 0.000009







4.step 0.000006







5.step 0.000009
```

It seems to work perfectly fine.
Maybe the code that you executed in the `for` loops was too small to take any time?

Comment: I would assume, your `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is larger than the OP's. AFAIR, it is 1000 for some Windows compilers which would make your results all `0.0000` as well.

Comment: @Gerhardh you mean lesser?
cause that's how you'll get a larger fraction right?

That makes sense tho

Comment: No, I mean larger. If the OP only has a value of `1000`, that means the shortest period is 1ms. Anything faster than that will not be measured correctly. If you get `0.000005` you must clearly have a `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` that is larger than `1000`.

Comment: You don't get the point. Maybe some basic ideas for you: `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is not only the value you divide by. It is also the base on taking time values, to start with. With smaller `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` `end-start` will be `<1` if the resolution is only `1ms` and the difference is less than 1ms. If the time period is 100µs and `CLOCKS_PER_SEC == 1000` then `(end-start)/1000 == (10-10)/1000 == 0.000`. While on your machine `(end-start)/1000000 == (10100-10000)/1000000 == 100/1000000 == 0.0001`

Answer (score 1):

Look at [man clock](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock)

> **CONFORMING TO**
>
> C89, C99, POSIX.1-2001. POSIX requires that CLOCKS_PER_SEC equals 1000000 independent of the actual resolution.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) says:

> **Notes**
>
> POSIX defines CLOCKS_PER_SEC as one million, regardless of the actual precision of clock.

That means, microseconds, you could do better via [clock_gettime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) with the clock `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`. Based on your implementation, nanosecond precision could be possible.

**Note:** `clock_gettime` is not C standard, conforms to POSIX.

---

**Example:**

```
typedef long nanos_t;

nanos_t now()
{
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &ts);
    return ts.tv_sec * 1000000000L + ts.tv_nsec;
}

nanos_t start, end;

start = now();
//some code
end = now();

printf("%li\n", end - start);
```